# .NET Standard & Platform target

Tags: uwp, arm, 64-bit, arm64, .net-standard-2.0

What I have understood, the *.NET Standard* is only specification of which  APIs to use when compiling the project. My goal is to use this *.NET Standard Class Library* in UWP and Xamarin project at the same time. This is fine, I can do that, everything compiles as expected.

My only concern is about how to target different Platforms: x86, x64, ARM and ARM64 for UWP and "others" for Xamarin?

For what is `Platform target` setting used in *.NET Standard Class Library* project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For what is Platform target setting used in .NET Standard Class Library project?

Platform target setting is `Debug|AnyCPU`, you could double click .NET Standard project you will find `PropertyGroup` following.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my concern how to compile .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library. However, I am still curious why there are "x86" and "x64" options for the "Platform target". Are they used for something or they're just sort of a legacy?

Comment: You could click solution platforms- > configuration manager, you will find the actual Platform target

Comment: Nico, I get that in Configuration Manager you can see the Platform targets. What I do not understand is why we should use any other value than 'Any CPU'. Does it make sense to switch .NET Standard Class Library to build specifically for e.g. x64?

Comment: it's  .NET Standard library, it will update platform target base on the main project.